# If "li" has this id, dont add active class

Tags: jquery

I'm a newbie in jQuery.

If the clicked element "li" has an id "disabled" then don't add the "active" class.

HTML:

```
<ul class="navigation-links">
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>
    <li id="disabled">test1</li>
    <li id="disabled">test2</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.active{
    color: red;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$("body").on("click", ".navigation-links li", function () {         
    if( $(".navigation-links li").is("#disabled") ){
        $(".navigation-links li").removeClass("active");
    }
    $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

Comment: if this is the exact case you have .. so you can just use `.on("click", ".navigation-links li:not(#disabled)", function()`

Comment: thank you @Mohamed-Yousef this worked for me ..
thank you thank you thank you.

Comment: you're totally welcome @VenRus .. but take care **id must be unique** so you'll need to check other answers

Comment: thanks for reminding about id. @Pete

Answer (score 0):

First of all, ids should be unique so use a class instead.  Then you can make use of jQuery's [`hasClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/)

```js
$("body").on("click", ".navigation-links li", function() {
  var $clickedLi = $(this);                                  // put the clicked element in a var
  
  $('.navigation-links li').not($clickedLi).removeClass("active"); // remove class from all li except clicked
  
  if (!$clickedLi.hasClass('disabled')) {                    // only do this if the clicked element 
    $clickedLi.toggleClass("active");                        // only toggle the class on the clicked li
  }
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="navigation-links">
  <li>test</li>
  <li>test</li>
  <li>test</li>
  <li class="disabled">test1</li>
  <li class="disabled">test2</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you @Pete i will choose this answer because is more logical, thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

try this

check `$(this).is("#disabled")` instead of `$(".navigation-links li").is("#disabled")`

```js
$("body").on("click", ".navigation-links li", function() {

  if (!$(this).is("#disabled")) {
      $(".navigation-links li").removeClass("active");
      $(this).addClass("active");
  }
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="navigation-links">
  <li>test</li>
  <li>test</li>
  <li>test</li>
  <li id="disabled">test1</li>
  <li id="disabled">test2</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$("body").on("click", ".navigation-links li", function() {

  if ($(this).attr('id')!='disabled') {
    $(this).addClass("active");
  }

  $(this).siblings().removeClass('active');
});


});
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="navigation-links">
  <li>test</li>
  <li>test</li>
  <li>test</li>
  <li id="disabled">test1</li>
  <li id="disabled">test2</li>
</ul>
```